# How translate css content with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this css:

```
.bs-docs-example::after {
  content: "Example";
}
```

is it possible translate with rails 3 the word `Example`?

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11577356/1297435) to your problem

Comment: I wont use `content` in that way. CSS should be used just for design.