# About i18n in rails and reversing the web site in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I decided to try to translate my rails app using `i18n` into Arabic language which right to left , unlike English language ( from left to right ) , how can I reverse my website in case of Arabic , and reset it back in case of choosing English ?

I tried `<html dir="rtl">` , it only changes the direction of the text , I need to make something like in facebook its change the whole site according to the selected language if its from R to L or L to R

How to make a condition to change between RTL and LTR in rails application ?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/

Comment: It's not for rails ! i cant use it in a rails app to change between LTR and RTL , or if you have a solution just you can write and explain it please.

Comment: Perhaps something like localizing the CSS file?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310044/rails-i18n-of-css-file

Comment: Believe it or not, Rails uses HTML...

Comment: and believe it or not , in Fedena rails application [Educational ERP SYSTEM] they have RTL support and the wrote in <html> a condition by ruby on rails between <%=> and use css also, which makes you able to use the RTL and LTR , so i need a solution in rails and css , because i dont know what they add in the other files !

Comment: look in (https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb)

Answer (score 1):

As i was searching for a similar problem, i encountered your question. Here is what i do.
in views:

```
<div class="some-css-class-<%= I18n.locale.to_s %>"> some content </div>
```

and then in your css files you should duplicate some classes.

For example if you had something like this:

```
.some-css-class{ align: left; }
```

you should change it to

```
.some-css-class-en{ align: left; } .some-css-class-ar{ align: right; }
```

Although i suggest that you define a direction variable in your layout or application_controller.rb or even application_helper.rb that specifies page direction: `@direction_page = (I18n.locale==:ar)?("rtl"):("ltr")` which is more expandable for future changes.